# Deleting from fetchedresultsController error no section at index

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and have not gotten anywhere. I'd love some help.
Im using a table with 2 fetches.  Only 1, which is in the last section of the table, can be edited.  When I delete an item the app crashes saying there is no section at index.  I've read a few responses to others similar question but still can't fix it.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count]+1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section < fetchedResultsController.sections.count) {
        return [[fetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:section]     numberOfObjects];
    }
    else {
        return fetchedResultsControllerCustomWOD.fetchedObjects.count;
    }
}
```

And for the commitEditing method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:    
(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[[fetchedResultsControllerCustomFR     objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // Remove device from table view
        [[fetchedResultsControllerCustomFR objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]     removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand all your fetch controllers right you are:

Deleting the object from CoreData once here:

```
 // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[[fetchedResultsControllerCustomFR     objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Then saving the context:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    return;
}
```

Which in turn alerts `fetchedResultsControllerCustomFR` that an item was deleted.

Which you then try to delete from `fetchedResultsControllerCustomFR` again:

```
// Remove device from table view
        [[fetchedResultsControllerCustomFR objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]     removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Which should already know it was gone. Given that you have your fetch controller delegates setup.

EDIT:

Wrap the delete call in -begin and -end calls:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: The last one was suppose to be commented out... but even when I do I get: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no section at index 14'

Comment: Thanks for the updated response but it crashed again.  Here is the console log: *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070
Also, I enabled objc_exception_throw and its output is: libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw:
0x2547e52:  pushl  %ebp
 if that helps.